# conda environment broken after deactivate/activate

Tags: python, conda

I am new to conda and am using conda environments in Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time and have come across an issue which I cannot find a solution for.

Starting with a basic miniconda installation I create an environment and install the packages I require for this project. I then run my code and everything works with no errors.

If I then deactivate the environment and activate it again my code does not work. I have libraries which cannot be found.

The only solution I have so far is to create a new environment each time and install the required packages again.

This is the process I use to create the environment etc:

```
$ conda create --name env  
$ source activate env  
$ conda install (theano, tensorflow, keras, other required packages)  
$ (run scripts to train a cnn, this works without any issues)  
$ source deactivate  
$ source activate env  
$ (run same script as above, does not work, cannot find -lcudnn)
```

I only get to the last line shown below before I start to experience issues. Theano cannot find -lcudnn even though it worked without any issue when the environment was first created.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'

import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import itertools
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show the exact commands that you use, and show your code?

Comment: My command for creating the environment is 'conda create --name env', I start the environment 'source activate env', Install relevant packages such as theano and keras, run my code to train a dnn' deactivate with 'source deactivate', reactivate in the same way and run the same code and theano cannot find -lcudnn

Comment: Can you please show the actual code that generates the error message?

Comment: I have updated the question above to show the code which causes issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case updating the conda solved the problem.

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```